# Update Select Option php

Tags: php, select

I can't get value of select option, this my script.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="category" id="e2" class="form-control">
    <?php
    require ("koneksi.php");
    $perintah="select * from t_category";
    $hasil=mysql_query($perintah);
    while ($dataCategory = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dataCategory['category']; ?>" selected><?php echo $dataCategory['category']; }?></option>

    <?php 
        echo'<script>
            $("#e2 option[value='.$data['category'].']").prop("selected", true);
        </script>';
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

i was used this script on my different project and this script work, but now can't work i don't now why, Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are in the log?

Comment: i check in console

"  home.php?p=prewedding-update&id=31:207 
Uncaught TypeError: "#e2 option[value=Pre Wedding]".prop is not a function at home.php?p=prewedding-update&id=31:207
(anonymous) @ home.php?p=prewedding-update&id=31:207  "

Answer (score 0):

Can you get selected option value?

Please try it:

Your selected option value show in console. I test it is fine.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="category" id="e2" class="form-control">
    <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");


    $query   = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM t_category");

    while ($dataCategory = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dataCategory['category']; ?>">
        <?php echo $dataCategory['category']; ?> 
    </option>

    <?php
    } 
    ?>
    </select>


    <script>
        $('#e2').change(function(){
            var opt = $("#e2 option:selected" ).val();
            console.log(opt); //output console log
        });
    </script> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response
Log "Uncaught TypeError" is no longer showing ...
But i still can not get the option value
T.T

Comment: still error in log? umm, I test it is work. But, I test my table data. https://image.ibb.co/gTag9a/screen.png

Comment: really thank again for response...
If the value of all the categories already appear,
But I still can not directly get the value that I chose before, I was want to make the edit menu

Comment: Can you send screenshot you want to design?

Comment: http://s1252.photobucket.com/user/novrystrife/media/1.png.html (When I click edit, the category menu is not the same as the category I choose)

Comment: If I use <? Php echo $ data ['category']; ?> Not a select option, I get the value

Comment: 'Prewedding' must be 'Wedding' at the title of form if you choice 'Wedding' from select option?

Comment: no, i mean wedding from select option must be prewedding, i want edit data test & test2, test & test2 at the category prewedding, when i select test & test2 for edit, the category in menu edit is wedding not prewedding T.T